# convert char * to wchar_t *

Tags: c++, wchar-t

I have a file.txt encoded in **gbk**, I read some bytes through `ifstream::read` and store them into a `char` buffer, then I want to print every word in the buffer in `gbk`.

I assume `wchar_t` is needed here, so I do it like this:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream ifs("./file.txt");
    char buf[256];
    ifs.read(buf, 255);

    wchar_t wbuf[256];
    mbstowcs( wbuf, buf, 255);
    for (int i = 0; i < wcslen(wbuf); i++)
        wprintf(L"%c ", wbuf[i]);

}
```

Am I doing it right? Or any better idea to do the job?

Thanks.

Comment: Fixed tags. This is C++ code, not C.

Comment: You need an external library such as `iconv` to convert GBK into something useful (such as WCHAR).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the wide-char specializations?  (`ifstream` and `wifstream` are template specializations of `basic_ifstream` over `char` and `wchar_t` respectively.)

```
wifstream wifs("./file.txt");
wifs.imbue(locale("zh_CN.GBK"));
wchar_t wbuf[256];
wifs.read(buf, 255);
```

Comment: +1, this is the standard way… although named locales aren't supported on all platforms.